# Calculate the domain of convergence of the series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Calculate the domain of convergence of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{z \ln (n)}.$$
I tried this:

$$ \\ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right| =\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{e^{z \ln (n+1)}}{e^{z \ln (n)}}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(n+1)^{z}}{n^{z}}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{z} \\ =\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{n}{n}+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{z}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{z}.$$

I don't know how to continue, I think that the limit is $1$, so, I don't know what the radius is, the other problem is how can I determine the domain.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the [Gauss test](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTest.html). By the binomial theroem $$
\left| {\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^z } \right| = \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^{\Re z}  = 1 + \frac{{\Re z}}{n} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right)
$$ for fixed $z$ and large $n$. You may also use the $p$-series test. Note also that this is not a power series, so there is no "radius" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is indeed 1, so the ratio test fails. If we temporarily assume that *z* is real, *z*=*x*, then your series is equivalent to
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } n^x$$
There is a well-known theorem which states that the series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
   \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges if and only if $p>1$. It then follows immediately that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } n^x$ converges if and only if $x<-1$. If *z* is complex, the series converges if and only if $\Re(z)<-1$

PS The theorem stated above can be proven by using the comparison test and integral test.